# SQL report with x and y field the same and z with 1 second difference

Tags: sql, time, informix

I tried to make a SQL report where the field x is the same in 2 different rows (like same NAME), filed y is the same in 2 different rows (like STATUS) but the field z is at one second difference (time to enter ar work). The format for z is hhmmss. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The datetime manipulation functions vary between them.

Comment: I need this in a control access system (Picture Perfect) with an INFORMIX database in a REDHAT LINUX environment.

Comment: Those are the SQL keywords and operators that apears in my report form (even if I used others like UNION or JOIN but never tried something like DATE, DATEADD or something like that)     SELECT SELECT * FROM FROM WHERE , ORDER BY ASC DESC LIKE " OR = < > <> <= >= _ % COUNT(*) MATCHES ? * BETWEEN AND COUNT DISTINCT( ( ) NOT IN SUM AVG MAX MIN IS NULL GROUP BY HAVING EXISTS

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever see my comments

Comment: @MichałPowaga see my comments

Comment: Would you like to treat those rows with different time as identical? If yes then do you have some limits to treats rows as the same let's say different up to 10 seconds or something like that?

Comment: @MichałPowaga I want to see in the results only the rows where time difference, on the same date and same person, are 1 seconds. The date field is yyyymmdd and is separated from time field hhmmss. This is the only case when a person can scan the badge to let someone else inside (someone without acces in that aria)

Comment: @MichałPowaga I found the RDBMS is about Informix-OnLine

Comment: @MichałPowaga I tried the 2 solutions but I get each time the error "There should be at least a single column in the result returned from the query:". Can this be done only with the keywords from my second comment?

Comment: @AditzaAditza check my edit, you'll have to probably correct column names (you haven't posted exact table schema).

Comment: You really need to document the schema of the table. If the time stamps stored in DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND you get one answer; if they are DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, you get another; if they are INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND you get a slightly different answer; if they're DECIMAL or INTEGER you get yet another; if they're CHAR or VARCHAR field, you get yet another answer. The mention of 'two different rows' suggests that you may need to know about self-joining and table aliases introduced with `tablename AS t1` notation.  When you say 'OnLine', do you mean version 5.20?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fields `NAME` (x), `STATUS` (y) and `TIME` (z) and assuming `TIME` is `datetime datatype`:

```
select t1.* from tablename t1
inner join tablename t2
  on t1.NAME = t2.NAME
  and t1.STATUS = t2.STATUS
  and t1.TIME = t2.time - 1 UNITS SECOND
```

Comment: In Informix, you don't need DATEADD; you could write `t2.time - 1 UNITS SECOND` or `t2.time - INTERVAL(1) SECOND`.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Informix but I think that following query should be fine. It should return first of two scans. Please mind that if gab between scans is longer than 1 second than it will not show up.

```
select t.name, t.status, t.data_field, t.time_field
from tab t
left join tab t1 on (
        t.name = t1.name and 
        t.status = t1.status and 
        t.data_field = t1.data_field and 
        (substring(t.time_field from 1 to 2)::INTEGER) * 3600 +
        (substring(t.time_field from 3 to 2)::INTEGER) * 60 +
        (substring(t.time_field from 5 to 2)::INTEGER) + 1 = 
        (substring(t1.time_field from 1 to 2)::INTEGER) * 3600 +
        (substring(t1.time_field from 3 to 2)::INTEGER) * 60 +
        (substring(t1.time_field from 5 to 2)::INTEGER)
    )
```

It uses [`substring`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst92.htm) function and [casting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.udr.doc/udr111.htm) to convert varchar time to seconds.

Comment: Informix DATETIME values are not VARCHAR, though they can be coerced to VARCHAR and SUBSTR (rather than SUBSTRING) would do the conversion if it is a pure time (DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND) field.  Things would be less happy if it is a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND or similar — but it is mainly a question of adjust the ranges.